# how to make a div gap shorter?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to shorter the gap between my "item" class (about me, trips, books, foods), for a responsive page. So I tried to decrease the height by setting them to pixels, and `margin:none`, and `padding:none`,but it didn't work. I also tried to put margins and padding away from `<a>`, which didn't work either. How can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/umklapper/4be1pus5/

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #edc9b5;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  padding: 35px;
}

.video {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    height: auto;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    border: none;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    margin: auto;
    padding: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  .item {
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
    border: none;
  }
  a {
    border: none;
    padding: none;
  }
  h1 {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .video,
  iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="index.html">Sung Min's Wolrd</a></h1>
<diV class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <p>Hey! Welcome to my website!</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</diV>
```

Comment: There are multiple wayouts. But the easiest one I can say is putting a negative margin value. (Not much recommended)

Comment: Remove "padding: 35px;" form item styles

Answer (score 0):

Slightly difficult to tell what you desire but this may help get you started.  Generally when you see a lot of CSS for a simple set of markup try to figure out what you can simply remove.

```css
.page-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.page-header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #edc9b5;
  border-right: 2px solid #808080;
  padding: 1em 1.2em 1em 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

.video {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <h1 class="page-header"><a href="index.html">Sung Min's World</a></h1>
  <diV class="wrapper page-body">
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="" class="item">About Me</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Trips</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Books</a>
      <a href="" class="item">Foods</a>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <p>Hey! Welcome to my website!</p>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </diV>
</diV>
```